# net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: angularjs, api, cors

Tenía una API en un servidor en el cuál funciona perfectamente.

Al migrarla al nuevo servidor, me ha dejado de funcionar, veo continuamente el `error: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` en chrome y `Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en https://xxx. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito)`.

Si pulso repetidas veces el botón de acceder, si que accede, pero no tiene sentido lo que está pasando.

Tengo dos hipótesis:

1. El nuevo servidor sirve el contenido en HTTP2 y angularjs no lo
   interpreta correctamente
2. La instalación de la API no ha sido correcta.

Respecto a la primera, voy a investigar como forzar a que el servidor responda en HTTP, a ver si así, por lo menos, soluciono el error, mientras investigo el porque del mismo.

Dato: Sólo falla con las peticiones `POST`, en las `GET` no sucede.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el que le haya pasado alguna vez, en mi caso, es porque IIS estaba sirviendo el contenido en HTTP 2, y a pesar de que Chrome, firefox, etc. estaban actualizados, no lo interpretaban bien.

He forzado a devolver el contenido en HTTP y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: como se hace eso en codigo?

Comment: Son configuraciones, no código. Por favor, revisar las normas para responder correctamente. Gracias!